# Java Passing array via jquery

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

i have action below

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "info_pure", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView GetInfo(String ser_name, String[] p_input_week_days, int p_input_month_day) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(JspView.PureInfoAup);       
        String aaa = request.getParameter("p_input_week_days");
```

i send get request to this action via jquery ajax.

```
 var myarray = ['Element 1', 'Element 2', 'Element 3'];

        var dataobject = {
            ser_name: p_ser_name.trim(), p_input_week_days: myarray, p_input_month_day: p_month_day
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '../info_pure',
            data: dataobject,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) { /// go forward
```

but when request send it give me an error. it says that my array parameter is null

here is my result on firebug

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spring MVC @RequestParam annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "info_pure", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView GetInfo(@RequestParam("p_input_week_days[]") String[] days) {   
    String[] aaa = days;
```

More details: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

Comment: add Jackson-Core and Jackson-mapper jars or dependencies in your project to have this functionality

Comment: yes it works after changing @RequestParam("p_input_week_days") to @RequestParam("p_input_week_days[]") ))

Comment: No need to add Jackson to classpath. This code does not use JSON conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this problem using Google Gson library.

Update your controller method like this

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "info_pure", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView GetInfo(String ser_name, String p_input_week_days, int p_input_month_day) {

      Gson gson=new Gson();
      String[] weeks=gson.fromJson(p_input_week_days, String[].class);
      // ....
```

Update your Ajax call like this

```
    var myarray = ['Element 1', 'Element 2', 'Element 3'];

    var dataobject = {
        ser_name: p_ser_name.trim(), p_input_week_days: JSON.stringify(myarray), p_input_month_day: p_month_day
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '../info_pure',
        data: dataobject,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) { /// go forward
```

Comment: No necessity to USE Gson

Comment: i do not want to use another library. i worked asp.net mvc for a years. there was it simpler. But @shoorick code works after changing @RequestParam("p_input_week_days") to @RequestParam("p_input_week_days[])